# AUC calculation in decision tree in scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Using scikit-learn with Python 2.7 on Windows, what is wrong with my code to calculate AUC? Thanks.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
iris = load_iris()
#print cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=10, scoring="precision")
#print cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=10, scoring="recall")
print cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=10, scoring="roc_auc")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/foo/PycharmProjects/CodeExercise/decisionTree.py", line 8, in <module>
    print cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=10, scoring="roc_auc")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1433, in cross_val_score
    for train, test in cv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 800, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 658, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 566, in _dispatch
    job = ImmediateComputeBatch(batch)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 72, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1550, in _fit_and_score
    test_score = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 1606, in _score
    score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\scorer.py", line 159, in __call__
    raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

**Edit 1**, looks like scikit learn could even decide threshold without any machine learning models, wondering why,

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y, scores, pos_label=2)
print fpr
print tpr
print thresholds
```

Comment: Sorry, I miss understood the question! `roc_auc` does not work for multiclass classification problems. But you can follow the link that juanpa.arrivillaga sent to you.

Comment: @MhFarahani, a bit lost. I think `AUC ` works for any classification problems, for multiple class, for any given class of a multi-class, we can draw its `AUC` by corrected classified to that specific class, and treat all remaining as another class? Then I can draw `AUC` for each class of multiple classes. Maybe I am not using the right term `AUC` here?

Comment: Yes, you can draw the AUC for each class separately. For that you need to binarize the output as you mentioned. Did you get the link that juanpa.arrivillaga sent or when I deleted my response that comment was also deleted?

Comment: @MhFarahani, good ask. I do not see any link, could you share again? BTW, why not add a reply, and I will mark it as answer to benefit people who has similar issues in the future.

Comment: Here is the link: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#multiclass-settings. My answer was not a complete answer, that's why I removed it! Someone else may have a better answer!

Comment: Thanks @MhFarahani, vote up for your reference. I studied the example, but confused if we binarize target `y`, then `y` will become a high dimension vector (in the example, 3 dimension) from scalar (of value 0, or 1 or 2), wondering how logistic regression handles it internally for dimension discrepancy between features (`x`) and target (`y`). I think features are still one dimension, but target is 3 dimension, how the prediction going to fit the model? If anything mis-understanding, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: I edited and undelete my previous answer. But regarding this question, in iris you have three classes (Setosa, Versicolour, and Virginica). For this data set, when you binarize your label, you need to apply the classification three times. Each time you consider one class 1 and the rest 0. For instance you set labels of Setosa 1 and the rest 0. Now you have a binary classification which is consistent with `roc_auc` implementation and the area under the curve is the value of `roc_auc` for Setosa. Similarly You can repeat the same procedure for  Versicolour, and Virginica as well.

Comment: @MhFarahani, thanks and your reply is insightful and you should recover it. My question is, for "binarize your label" you mean call function `label_binarize `? Or you mean manually change the target `y` from `0,1,2` into `0 and 1`? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, binarize iris.target using `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer`. Also,
watch this introduction from Andrew Ng. He is explaining how one-vs-all: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zj403m-fjqg

Comment: @MhFarahani, I know what means one vs all, my question is more about mis-matched dimension. I think after `LabelBinarizer`, `y` will become 3 dimensional, correct? But when predict from features, prediction result is one dimension, how does one dimension predicted results fits into 3 dimensional target? Thanks.

Comment: @MhFarahani, you can refer to example here (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html), I think we have to use `y_score[:, i]` to extract only one dimension from binarized label, or else, model will not know how to compare one dimension to 3 dimension, correct?

Comment: Yes, y would have three columns (one for each class) but notice that you need to pass your estimator to `sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier`. It will take care of fitting your estimator three times (the x to one of the y columns at the time). Therefore, the returned score also have 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks @MhFarahani, do you mean `OneVsRestClassifier` internally will see a binary 3 dimension vector of y, and it will handle the issue that for each one of the 3 individual `OneVsRestClassifier`, it will only predict as `0` or `1`, other than predict a 3 dimensional vector, correct? If so, it could answer my question why prediction result for each class is a scalar, but binary label result is a 3 dimension vector, which does not match prediction scalar results. :)

Comment: @MhFarahani, another confusion is, I am confused by this line of code `fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])`, `y_test[:, i]` is the real result for classification, and `y_score[:, i]` is the prediction results => In the sample you mentioned (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html). Just curious how they are used to draw roc? I think roc needs tpr and fpr according to different model threshold, but in this example, model only score/trained once. If I mis-understand anything, please feel free to correct me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in each iteration in `OneVsRestClassifier` the estimator is fitted to X and one column of y (y[ i ] (i=1,2,3)). In each y[ i ] one class is 1 and the other two classes are 0. Therefore, you have three scores for three fits. `y_test[:, i]` is the real labels and `y_score[:, i]` is the probabilities of being the desired class. fpr[ i] and tpr[ i ] are false positive and true positive rates for each class given the thresholds. Given these values, `auc` function is a trapezoid integration method that calculates the area under the curve.

Comment: Thanks @MhFarahani, for the reply, as you said in order to draw ROC curve, we need the same model with different threshold, but in the example code, I do not see the model is with different threshold? It just train the model once. If I mid-read anything, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: You need to go to GitHub and look at sklearn code to see how they apply the thresholds. The thresholds are built in `roc_curve`, and it really does not matter what are all the thresholds! You need to know the threshold that maximizes the area under the curve. But for your reference, in the example `fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])`, the third variable that roc_curve returns is the thresholds (i.e. `_` ).

Comment: Thanks @MhFarahani, vote up for your reply. I post some code in edit 1 section and you can refer to it, and I am following your advice to explore the 3rd return value of threshold from `roc_curve`. My confusion is, it seems scikit learn could even decide threshold without using any machine learning models? How does it work without any machine learning models?

Answer (score 1):

The `roc_auc` in `sklearn` works only with binary class:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html

One way to move around this issue is to binarize your label and extend your classification to a one-vs-all scheme. In sklearn you can use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer`. The documentation is here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html

Comment: Thanks MhFarahani, but it seems KFold does not allow me to specify scoring parameter like `precision`, `recall`, etc. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html

Comment: @LinMa KFold merely breaks up the data into different training and testing sets, you then have to do the scoring yourself. See this [link on your exact situation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#multiclass-settings).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for pointing to the sample and it is exactly what I need. My question is after we call `label_binarize`, `y` becomes a 3 dimensional vector other than a scalar value, I think when doing prediction, the prediction result is a scalar value, wondering how could a scalar value match the dimension of `y` (which is 3 dimension).

Comment: Hi MhFarahani, thanks for the great reference, and it is exactly what I need. My question is after we call `label_binarize`, `y` becomes a 3 dimensional vector other than a scalar value, I think when doing prediction, the prediction result is a scalar value, wondering how could a scalar value match the dimension of `y` (which is 3 dimension).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 2nd part of your question posted under 'Edit 1':

1. roc_curve function doesn't find optimum threshold for prediction
2. roc_curve generates set of tpr and fpr by varying thresholds from 0 to 1  [given y_true and y_prob(probability of positive class)]
3. In general, if roc_auc value is high, then your classifier is good. But you still need to find the optimum threshold that maximizes a metric such as F1 score when using the classifier for prediction
4. In an ROC curve, the optimum threshold will correspond to a point on the ROC curve that is at maximum distance from the diagonal line(fpr = tpr line)